# Import filtered data using DTS

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to use DTS to import filtered data. I am using the import and export wizard to import some data from one instance to another instance. I would like to know if there is a way to specify to import records that matches a filter. (for eg: say records with date of today).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of SQL you are using, I'm guessing 2000 since DTS has been deprecated.  But if all you want to do is move data from one instanct to another I would recommend the Import/Export wizard, and then select the **"Write a query to specify data"** option.  That way you can get the exact data you want in a familiar tsql way.

You typically can access this wizard by right clicking the database you are either copying to (or from) and select Import (or export).